# PostgreSQL timestamp Grammer

Tags: postgresql

```sql
SELECT * FROM items WHERE created_time >= 20210505143012999
```

on mySQL, we can give condition like `WHERE created_time >= 20210505143012999`.

but, I want to find it with similar format(20210505143012999) on PostgreSQL.. How can I do this?

Comment: Is that an integer or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems mySQL is a little lax with data types (or perhaps just more forgiving), in Postgres your value is just an number (bigint). You need to convert it with the [to_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html) function. But as an epoch it seems Postgres does not like and it also does not appear to be an epoch either. You can either pre-convert to a string then use the to_timestamp of cast it as test within the function parameters. Either way specify the format: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1d026467b50f6195a9faa514fd069229))

```
select to_timestamp ('20210505143012999', 'yyyymmddhh24missms');

select to_timestamp (20210505143012999::text, 'yyyymmddhh24missms');
```